# Updating the supported tags for pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install Tensorflow, and received the following error.

> tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

By reading through other questions, I think I've traced the issue to the cp35 tag not being supported by the version of pip I have installed. What's odd is that I believe I installed python 3.5 and the latest version of pip (9.0.1), but have the following supported tags:

> [('cp27', 'cp27m', 'win_amd64'), ('cp27', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('py2', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('cp27', 'none', 'any'), ('cp2', 'none', 'any'), ('py27', 'none', 'any'), ('py2', 'none', 'any'), ('py26', 'none', 'any'), ('py25', 'none', 'any'), ('py24', 'none', 'any'), ('py23', 'none', 'any'), ('py22', 'none', 'any'), ('py21', 'none', 'any'), ('py20', 'none', 'any')]

How can I go about modifying the supported tags, or is that even the right approach?

Comment: Are you using the command `pip` directly, or `pip-3.5`, or `python3.5 -m pip` to install things? The first may be a pip for another Python version (Python 2.7 then, judging from the listed tags).

Comment: I tried pip-3.5 and got this:


`'pip-3.5' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Apologies if I should know what this means. I'm a MATLAB/C/Java guy, and very much new to python.

Comment: Your Python 3.5 installation probably hasn't come with pip, and you need to install it for Python 3.5. But first, try `python3.5 -m pip` and see what it says. If it isn't happy, try `python3.5 -m ensurepip` next; that may install `pip`.

Comment: "I'm a MATLAB/C/Java guy, and very much new to python." Doesn't have much to do with that, tbh, but with system adminstration & installation.

Comment: `'python3.5' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Seems that isn't there either.

Comment: Ah; now you're probably up to Windows installation and path settings and such. Perhaps the command is `python3`, but there really should be a `python3.5`. So either it's badly or not installed, or your path settings don't include it. That's hard to tell without seeing your system.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having this problem on windows then it's most likely that you have python 3.6.

Tensorflow for python 3.6 on windows is not available atm unless you want to go through some hassle.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6999
"In the meantime, if you need the pip package for windows for a python version other than py 3.5, you will need to build from sources. We are sorry for the inconvenience."

If you wish to use Anaconda Python then tensorflow page is leading to the python 3.6 download which won't work. Python 3.5 Anaconda you can get from the Anaconda archive https://repo.continuum.io/archive/ or use the direct link
https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when I run this command. I found error that the installed version of python was x86 and TensorFlow is for x64 versions. I reinstalled the python with x64 version and it works now! I hope this works for you too!